# How to map this ER model to actual tables?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

Suppose we have an ER-design problem like this:

> A pharmaceutical company sells its products throughout a country. For the ease of sales, the entire country is divided into some Areas. Areas have sales personnel. The company has various types of products that are classified into categories. Each category has specific commission rates. There are storage facilities in Areas. Sales personnel take products from storage facilities and deliver them to outlets. Records of daily sales are kept. Sales personnel receive commissions according to their monthly sales performances, receives bonuses according to their half-yearly sales performances, and, receives promotions according to their yearly performances.

This is my step-by-step solution:

**Step 1: Regular Entity Type mapping.**

Area{***Number***, Name}

ProductCategory{***CategoryName***, CommissionRate}

Product{***ID***, Name}

Employee{***ID***, Name}

EmployeeType{***TypeName***}

Sales{***ReceiptNumber***, Date, Qty}

**Step 2: Mapping Weak Entity Type.**

Area{***Number***, Name}

ProductCategory{***CategoryName***, CommissionRate}

Product{***ID***, Name}

Storage{Qty, AreaNumber}  ???? what can be the partial key and primary-key?

Employee{***ID***, Name}

EmployeeType{***TypeName***}

Sales{***ReceiptNumber***, Date, Qty}

Performance {CommissionAmount, BonusAmount, EmployeeID} ??? what can be the partial key and primary-key?

**Step 3: Mapping binary 1:1 relationship.**

Area{***Number***, Name}

ProductCategory{CategoryName, CommissionRate}

Product{***ID***, Name, ProductCategoryName}

Storage{Qty, AreaNumber}  ????

Employee{***ID***, Name}

EmployeeType{***TypeName***}

Sales{***ReceiptNumber***, Date, Qty}

Performance {CommissionAmount, BonusAmount} ????

**Step 4: Mapping binary 1:N relationship.**

Area{***Number***, Name}

ProductCategory{***CategoryName***, CommissionRate}

Product{***ID***, Name, ProductCategoryName, Storage}  ????

Storage{Qty, AreaNumber} ????

Employee{***ID***, Name, AreaNumber, EmployeeTypeName}

EmployeeType{***TypeName***}

Sales{***ReceiptNumber***, Date, Qty, EmployeeID}

Performance {CommissionAmount, BonusAmount, EmployeeID, NewEmployeeType} ????

**Step 4: Mapping binary M:N relationship.**

Area{***Number***, Name}

ProductCategory{***CategoryName***, CommissionRate}

Product{***ID***, Name, ProductCategoryName, Storage}  ????

Storage{Qty, AreaNumber}   ????

Employee{***ID***, Name, AreaNumber, EmployeeTypeName}

EmployeeType{***TypeName***}

Sales{***ReceiptNumber***, Date, Qty, EmployeeID}

Performance {CommissionAmount, BonusAmount, EmployeeID, NewEmployeeType}  ????

ProductSales {ProductID, ReceiptNumber} ???? Is the relationship between Product and Sales, M:N????

How to fix the existing problems and how to improve the solution?

Comment: 1. There is no one method. What is a reference for the one you are marked on? 2. There are 2 phases, ER design then map to database schema. Is your ER design fixed, and we're just doing the mapping? Or are you also asking about ER design for your application?

Comment: @philipxy, I am actually asking for mapping. But, you can suggest possible upgrades and corrections.

Answer (score 0):

You need these tables; Area, Product, Stock (storage), Category, Employee, Sale.

Your description doesn't mention any need for employee type and performance is extracted from sales. Your examples miss connecting stock to items so you can search by item and area. From these all your requirements can be met.

Comment: "Your description doesn't mention any need for employee type" --- but, what about promotions and designation changes?

Comment: Those are just one or more fields in the employee record.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions and a few other issues:

> ProductCategory{CategoryName, CommissionRate}

The problem statement says there are commmission rates (plural) per Category. We have to assume it's M:N.

> EmployeeType{TypeName}

Probably unnecessary; the problem is all about sales people.

> Sales{ReceiptNumber, Date, Qty}

Total quantity on a reciept is normally a function of its product quantities and prices plus other things. You could account for the other things by a separate Qty like this or take the other things for granted and get the total quantity from the itemized lines of the receipt (below).

> Storage{Qty, AreaNumber}
>   ???? what can be the partial key and primary-key?

A storage facility would probably be a regular entity; PK ID plus attribute Name, N:1 with an area so add FK attribute Area. As a weak entity, add a storage facility number per area; PK is (StorageNumber, AreaNumber). AreaNumber is a partial key (FK).

Quantity at a storage facility is per product, which we call stock. That's an M:N relationship on a storage facility and product or weak entity of both. So relationship Stock with either StorageID or (StorageNumber, AreaNumber) (FK) plus ProductID (FK), together forming PK.

> Performance {CommissionAmount, BonusAmount, EmployeeID}
>   ??? what can be the partial key and primary-key?
>   Performance {CommissionAmount, BonusAmount} ????

Everything about a performance given an employee and date is determined by other entities & relationships. So we don't need to manifest/reify them. But if so, best a weak entity. PK (EmployeeID, Date). EmployeeID is a partial key (FK).

> Performance {CommissionAmount, BonusAmount, EmployeeID, NewEmployeeType} ????

An employee apparently has a level/position to which they can be promoted. That would be an attribute of Employee. Although as before this is determined by sales so not strictly necessary.

> Product{ID, Name, ProductCategoryName, Storage} ????

Product to product category is M:N and to Storage is M:N but these are two separate M:N relationships, each with its own table, and should not be mixed with each other or non-key Product attributes. (Presumably this table holds rows where "product ID with name Name in product category with name ProductCategoryName is stored at facility Storage". So every (product, product category) pair has have a row in it for every facility the product is stored in.)

> ProductSales {ProductID, ReceiptNumber}
>   ???? Is the relationship between Product and Sales, M:N????

A given product and receipt determine a total quantity and/or price for that product, but that's not normally a relationship of interest, nor is any other on these. We do want to know whether "line ItemNumber on receipt ReceiptNumber has product ProductID in quantity Qty at price Price". We can consider a line to be a weak entity of its receipt and product. So Item{ItemNumber, ReceiptNumber,ProductID,Qty,Price} with (ItemNumber,ReciptNumber,ProductID) as PK, with attributes Qty and Price. (ItemNumber, ReceiptNumber) and ProductID are partial keys (FKs).

> Sales personnel take products from storage facilities and deliver them to outlets.

The symmetry of storage facilities and outlets suggests the latter should be modeled in a like way to Storage, with a Stock for each. Then we can reconcile StorageStock, OutletStock and Sales.